# GitHub CI Test Error: relation does not exist. (DRF as BE)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, continuous-integration

I am working on a project based on Django Rest Framework and I got some CI Test errors when I try to merge my branch to main. Before I merge to main, **I have already made some Django Unit Tests and they all can pass locally.** (My database is Postgres)

Here is the error detail:

[image]

I have never faced this error locally. I tried to re-migration and migrate the database but it still fails in the CI test. Dose this because the CI test and Django test have different operation logic? Or is it because I have a problem with the processing of the Postgres?